# How to keep DIV visible after postback

Tags: javascript, css

I cant seem to get div to stay visible after post back. Is there any thing wrong with the visibility portion?

```
function toggleOverlay(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
        overlay.style.opacity = .8;
        if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
            overlay.style.display = "none";
            specialBox.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            specialBox.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Start Overlay -->
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <!-- End Overlay -->
    <!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
    <div id="specialBox"  runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript"> if(Page.IsPostBack)

                {
                     specialBox.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
                }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the same property in your server side code as in your client-side code.

```
 <script runat="server"> 
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        specialBox.Style["display"] = "block";
    }
</script>
```

In CSS there are two ways to hide/show elements:

display: none or block/inline/inline-block => hides the element and removes the space it was taking
visibility: hidden / visible => hides the elements and makes the occupied space blank

If either one of these are set to their hidden values, the element will not be visible

Apart from that, your script-tag also says `"text/javascript"`, where you really want to execute server-side code, so I added a `runat="server"`-attribute

Comment: Replace your last script-block with the one I put in my answer